# Is it possible that an arcade game was only released on arcade and not on video game console?

Tags: arcade

I spoke with my brother about an old arcade game we liked to play inside an arcade room when we were children. He told me this game was never released on video game console, is that possible? I think all arcade games can be found and be played on video game consoles.

Comment: To the VTC'er: *how* is this unclear?

Comment: You might be able to play a lot of arcade games with an emulator these days, but a lot back then wouldn't be suited to console or home pc

Comment: Also keep in mind that in *today's* gaming industry, it's fairly trivial to release a game on multiple platforms. There are many widely supported *game engines* that provide a common basis to build your game from, while still allowing it to run on multiple platforms without too much extra effort. That didn't exist in the 80s. You might've been able to copy/paste *some* parts of your code to release on different hardware, but you'd also have to rewrite a lot of it, too. And re-test - no option for day one patches back then. Releasing on multiple platforms was a lot more work than it is now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there's quite a few actually.

Wikipedia has a nice [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Arcade-only_games) of them.

Comment: Nice list. I'd say the vast majority of arcade games never appeared on consoles. However in the 8-bit era (and the early 16 bit era) home computers were more popular as home gaming machines outside the US and Japan than true consoles. A good number of the titles listed there probably had fairly close unofficial ripoffs on the 8-bits.